# Extra indents in adaptive-wrap mode only for lines beginning with \item

Tags: latex, indentation, wrapping

When using the `adaptive-wrap` mode in the plain `latex-mode` (no `AUCTeX`), I want to give extra indents to only lines beginning with "`\item`". For example, I currently have:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a very very very very very very very (soft-wrap here)
very very very very very very long line.

  And this is another very very very very very very (soft-wrap here)
  very long line.
\end{itemize}
```

Note that there are two leading white-spaces at the beginning of the second paragraph ("  And this is ..."), which wraps by `adaptive-wrap` nicely to my eyes. Now I would also like the paragraph beginning with "\item This is ..." to wrap with extra indentation even though it has no leading white-spaces. That is, I would like it displayed as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item This is a very very very very very very very (soft-wrap here)
  very very very very very very long line.

  And this is another very very very very very very (soft-wrap here)
  very long line.
\end{itemize}
```

Please note the indentation at the beginning of the line next to the first soft-wrap. Could I do it somehow? Any help would be appreciated.

Globally setting `adaptive-wrap-extra-indent` to 2 makes all lines have 2 extra indents, which I want to avoid. I would like only the line beginning with "`\item`" have the effect.

Thank you.

PS. I am already very happy with the combination of `latex-mode` and `adaptive-wrap`, and this is the final issue I would like to resolve. I have the following in my .emacs file with some other stuff.

```
(load-library "adaptive-wrap")
(visual-line-mode 1)
(adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode 1)
(whitespace-newline-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I added the following in `.emacs`, after `(load-library "adaptive-wrap")`:

```
(load-library "adaptive-wrap")

;;; added from here
(defun begin-with-item-p ()
  "Determine whether the beginning of line is \\item"
  (let ((curpos (point)))
    (beginning-of-line)
    (setq ret (looking-at "[    ]*\\\\item[^A-Za-z]"))
    ;; Above, [    ] is SPC followed by TAB (ctrl-q TAB)
    (goto-char curpos) ret))

;; HACK https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/adaptive-wrap-0.5.1.el
(defun adaptive-wrap-prefix-function (beg end)
  "Indent the region between BEG and END with adaptive filling."
  (goto-char beg)
  (while (< (point) end)
    (let ((lbp (line-beginning-position)))
      ;; ---- BEGIN ------------------------------------------------
      (setq adaptive-wrap-extra-indent (if (begin-with-item-p) 2 0))
      ;; ---- END --------------------------------------------------
      (put-text-property (point)
                         (progn (search-forward "\n" end 'move) (point))
                         'wrap-prefix
                         (adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix lbp (point))))))
;;; added to here
```

This piece of codes replace `adaptive-wrap-prefix-function`. The amount of indentation is hard-coded (`2` and `0`), but I can always edit the part if I want.